# Double match highlighting for specific identifiers or filetypes

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

While using https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown I discovered that markdown headers are html identifiers. An `h2` markdown header has two identifiers tied to it: `['mkdNonListItemBlck', 'htmlH2']`.

I'm unsure if I'm able to "double" match and define the colors for that selection or if I should only execute `htmlh2` highlighting if the file is of type `markdown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to adapt the colors, you need to find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. It's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. Or just try which `:highlight` command changes the colors.

Many syntax scripts are hierarchical, i.e. a text is matched by multiple syntax rules. Without looking deeply into this particular Markdown syntax, I'd guess `mkdNonListItemBlock` is a generic block, and `htmlH2` comes from the original HTML syntax.

---

> Rephrasing my last question: I only want to highlight `htmlH2` if I'm in a markdown file. I was hoping to "double" match both groups and then set the highlight preference.

That's unfortunately not possible. Highlight groups like `htmlH2` are global; that's why the convention prefixes them with the filetype (`html`). If you redefine the colors, that will always apply to both HTML and Markdown.

You could write `:autocmd WinEnter` to toggle them back and forth between HTML and Markdown buffers (and never view both in splits at the same time), or copy-and-paste the syntax stuff from `syntax/html.vim` into `syntax/mkd.vim` and then rename `htmlH2` to `mkdH2`, but I wouldn't recommend either hack.

Comment: I hope I could answer your question; your last sentence doesn't make sense to me. There's no "double matching", and you don't "execute" highlighting. To change colors, you redefine the highlight group of the corresponding syntax group name.

Comment: The current identifiers that are syntax groups that are highlighting the headers. `['mkdNonListItemBlck', 'htmlH2']`

Rephrasing my last question: I only want to highlight `htmlH2` if I'm in a markdown file. I was hoping to "double" match both groups and then set the highlight preference.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Good idea, but unfortunately not possible. See my edit.

Comment: What if only applied the styles if filetype are `markdown` with a function? I'm assuming this is inappropriate for a colors file, but would it be acceptable in another compartment of the vim-plugin itself?

Comment: That's what I've hinted at; with `:autocmd WinEnter * if &filetype == 'markdown' | hi htmlH2 ... | else | hi htmlH2 ... | endif`. It works, unless you expect to see both HTML and Markdown at the same time.

Comment: hmm, I was more so thinking of when the buffer is read or opened I would check the filetype and then execute the highlights. This is the track I'm going to go with! Thank you :)

Comment: As long as you never have both HTML and Markdown in a single Vim session, that would be fine as well.